# Embedding a hyperlink or button in the appointment label of a SchedulerControl

Tags: c#, winforms, calendar, devexpress

For quick reference on the principle control I'm working with:

[What Is An Appointment](http://www.devexpress.com/Help/?document=XtraScheduler/CustomDocument1753.htm&levelup=true)

The client has a very specific, ackward request. Modify the Appointment Label on the DevExpress SchedulerControl so that the user can click or double click on a person's Name and go to their profile instead of the appointment edit form. The subject field text is currently set up to hold the name and phone number.

The problem is that AppointmentLabels aren't equipped for that, there is no container attached to the appointment label to insert any kind of hyperlink, button control, or anything like that. Something like this would be no problem in ASP.NET using the item Templates. I've tried negotiating for some things I thought would achieve the same effect while leveraging extensibility the SchedulerControl supports, such as putting the profile link in the edit form (too many button clicks!) or a custom in-place editor or prepared pop-up menu (too confusing for users!); this is the only UI design the client will accept.

So is it even possible to put a hyperlink control inside the appointment label of a SchedulerControl?

Comment: Still no answer? Am I not explaining the problem clearly enough?

Answer (score 1):

Based on the number of views I'd say no one cares at all about this question. I sent the same question to DevExpress itself. Here's a link in case someone cares to know what their response is.

[Hyperlink in an AppointmentLabel](http://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/p/Q200348.aspx)